# jQuery: using hover to roll-over multiple images at once

Tags: jquery, rollover

I have a small problem, but I'm a bit stumped.

I am using the following code to do rollovers on my webpage

```
$("#mylink1 img").hover(
 function()
 {
  this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
 },
 function()
 {
  this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
 }
);
```

This works great for individual images, but I would like to roll over one of them and have the the other one change as well.

```
<a id="mylink1" href="about.cfm"><img src="images/Home_top_navs/aboutus_manage_off.gif" /></a>

<a id="mylink1" href="about.cfm"><img src="images/Home_top_navs/aboutus_nav2_off.gif" /></a>
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change id to string @corroded suggested. IDs should be unique within a page.

As for changing multiple images when hovering over a single image, you have to modify the hover over and out functions. Currently, they are only changing the `src` attribute of the image currently hovered over. Instead, inside both the functions, you have to loop through each image and change the `src` attribute. Something like:

```
$("#mylink1 img").hover(
    function() {
        $(".mylink1 img").each(function() {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
        });
    },
    function() {
        $(".mylink1 img").each(function() {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
        });
    }
);
```

You can avoid the duplication with some currying:

```
(function() {
    var images = $(".mylink1 img");

    function imageSwapper(imgs, from, to) {
        return function() {
            imgs.each(function() {
                this.src = this.src.replace(from, to);
            });
        };
    }

    $(images).hover(
        imageSwapper(images, "_off", "_on"),
        imageSwapper(images, "_on", "_off")
    );
})();​
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! (But I think the first line might be a typo.) I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use id, use class because id is unique.

```
<a class="mylink1" href="about.cfm"><img src="images/Home_top_navs/aboutus_manage_off.gif"  /></a>

<a class="mylink1" href="about.cfm"><img src="images/Home_top_navs/aboutus_nav2_off.gif" /></a>
```

then:

```
$(".mylink1 img").hover(
```